# Android N Notification Direct Reply

Tags: android, notifications

Recently I read new Article about [Android N notification Updates](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-updates.html) where google has mentioned about **Direct Reply** I have tried my best to learn from this article but I am not getting exactly how to reply directly from notification. If any one can guide me for this then I would be very much thankful.

[I want to implement like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAQGa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ever created a notification using pre-Android N versions then it will be a easy task for you. Because they introduced this direct reply feature as addition to existing notification builder

**There are mainly 2 additions that we need to make. They are as follows,**

1. RemoteInput
2. Reply Action

As these additions are optional. i.e, If you are creating notifications with NotificationCompat.Builder then you will get new look of notification with standard style without adding any code.

When we create Direct Reply we basically provide an additional Reply Action with a RemoteInput to Notification Builder and everything else will be same as earlier API.

**The below is a guide for how to add direct reply feature to an existing notification**

*if you want backward compatibility then use **NotificationCompat.Builder** instead **Notification.Builder***

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code

```
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action replayAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Replay", PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 1, new Intent[]{new Intent(this, ReplayActivity.class)}, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .addRemoteInput(new RemoteInput.Builder("KEY").setAllowFreeFormInput(true).setLabel("Enter text you want to send").build())
                .build();

android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icons) // Must Required  
                .addAction(replayAction); 
                 ...// Notification Configuration


android.app.NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mgr.notify(1, builder.build());
```

------ In ReplayActivity.class -----

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_replay);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Bundle remoteInput = android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);

        if (remoteInput != null) {
            String s = (String) remoteInput.getCharSequence("KEY");
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Do whatever with Text 
        }
    }
```